# How to get vscode help > about information

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-api

[image: info]

I am developing an extension using the vscode API.
How do I get the help > about information in the top menu of vscode?

Not the entire text,
but if I want to get the OS I want to get the string Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **OS** entry in Help/About, you can use the **os API** available in  **Node.JS**. Specifically the `type()`, `arch()` and `release()` functions.

Something like this will return the exact same content:

```js
   const os = require("node:os");

   console.log(`OS: ${os.type()} ${os.arch()} ${os.release()}`);
```

Tested on Windows and MacOS computers.